# How do I deal with /dev/xvda1 mounted on / usage full problem?

Tags: mount, disk-usage

OS: Ubuntu 18.04

As I did a "df -h", it shows that my "/dev/xvda1" is 100% full. I cannot even do a "tab" to list all folders/files under current directory. ( I got a "-bash: cannot create temp file for here-document: No space left on device" error).
Is it possible that I could get the "/dev/xvdb1" mounted on the top directory "/" so that I will have ample space to install libraries, etc.

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            4.8G     0  4.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           985M   95M  890M  10% /run
/dev/xvda1      8.5G  7.8G  246M  100% /
tmpfs           4.9G     0  4.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           4.9G     0  4.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/xvdb1      196G  9.4G  177G   6% /datadrive
tmpfs           985M     0  985M   0% /run/user/1003
```

This is the information when I logged in:

```
  System information as of Tue Oct 20 11:48:32 PDT 2020

  System load:                    0.44
  Usage of /:                     91.8% of 8.49GB
  Memory usage:                   13%
  Swap usage:                     0%
  Processes:                      145
```

These are the directories taking up the most space:

```
$ sudo du -xch -d 3 / | awk '$1~/G/'
1.7G /usr/lib 
4.1G /usr 
1.2G /var/lib 
1.4G /var 
1.1G /lib 
7.8G / 
7.8G total
```

Comment: Please run `sudo du -xch -d 3 / | awk '$1~/G/' > /datadrive/sizes` and then post the contents of the new file `sizes` in your question. That will show us which directoris under `/` are taking up the most space and then we can help you move them to `/datadrive`.

Comment: Sorry I do not know how to do pretty formatting with the data:

1.7G    /usr/lib         4.1G    /usr        1.2G    /var/lib        1.4G    /var            1.1G    /lib         7.8G    /           7.8G    total

Comment: Now I am using "parted" to resize the partition. What does "Warning: Partition /dev/xvda1 is being used. Are you sure you want to continue?" mean?
Is it safe to expand existing partition? Will any files be deleted due to the resizing?